# Self-avoiding walk on lattice with minimum walk distance to adjacent cells

Tags: combinatorics

I have a 2-dimensional square lattice with rectangular bounds, an array if you will.

I would like to find the self-avoiding walk over the whole lattice that minimizes the walk distance between cells adjacent to each other, in terms of the 8-neighborhood.

So for example, if I view a 3x3 window around one cell, I would like the most cells to be within a walk distance of 8 (or *n*) on average. A naive approach would be to just scan the lattice line-by-line, but then only 2 of 8 neighbors would be nearby.

I seem to recall there was such a thing, but can't find it.

Bonus questions:

- Is there a closed formula for the function *lattice coordinates* -> *walk step* ?
- Can it be generalized to 3 or more dimensions?